# How do I make one ReactJS Store dependent on another Store?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, flux

ReactJS I think I understand, but Flux has me baffled.  I feel like the simplest tasks now require exponentially more code and complexity.

I'm trying to report on some data using graphs and lists.  What I created is a "WindowStore" which holds the "start" and "end" times representing a reporting period (one day by default).  I've got buttons in a component to move forward and backward one hour at a time.

In the component's render() method, I'm returning this (as part of a larger component):

```
<button onClick={this.stepBack} type="button"
        className="btn btn-default btn-xs" 
        disabled={this.state.loading}>
        <i className="fa fa-angle-double-left fa-2x"></i>
</button>
```

I've got this handler in my component:

```
stepBack: function() {
    WindowActions.stepBack();
}
```

WindowActions.stepBack dispatches a message to the WindowStore to update the start and end values:

```
stepBack: function() {
    Dispatcher.dispatch({type: WindowConstants.Actions.STEP_BACK});
}
```

The WindowStore traps STEP_BACK and decrements the start and end values by 1 hour.  It emits a change event, and the component updates the graph boundaries using the new state "start" and "end" values.

I have a second store that records the data for a graph, GraphStore.  The data gets populated from a AJAX call to the server in GraphActions, ideally using the start and end values from WindowStore (note:  I trimmed out the error handling):

```
refresh: function(start, end) {
    Api.getGraphData(start, end, function(reply) {
        Dispatcher.dispatch({
            type: GraphConstants.Actions.Refresh, 
            results: reply.data
        });
    });
}
```

I can call refresh() in componentDidMount() to update the graph at start:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        window: WindowStore.getState(),
        graph: GraphStore.getState()
    }
}, 

componentDidMount: function() {
    GraphActions.refresh(this.state.window.start, this.state.window.end);
}
```

Here's my mental block:  what I'd like to do then is refresh the data when the window moves.  How/where should I make this call?  I feel like my graph component should call GraphActions.refresh() when the state changes, but this is obviously a dispatch chain, so no go.  The only alternative I can find is to have WindowActions.stepBack call GraphActions.refresh.  But that means I have to pass in the new start and end values as well as tightly couple GraphActions to WindowActions:

```
stepBack: function(start, end) {
    Dispatcher.dispatch({type: WindowConstants.Actions.STEP_BACK});
    GraphActions.refresh(start, end);
}
```

Is this right?  What do I do when I want to update a list component or other graph components drawing from the same WindowStore?  Am I supposed to call those in stepBack too?  What if I need the data loaded by GraphActions.refresh() and I want to wait for refresh to finish?  This feels too tightly coupled and messy.

Please help.

Comment: Can u share your component source code and window store source code

Comment: Implement a `waitFor` function or use the flux libs `waitFor`. https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/dispatcher.html#content

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flux [`waitFor()`](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/dispatcher.html) function

So you have 2 stores registered to the same dispatcher and have one store waitFor the other store to process the action first then the one waiting can update and dispatch the change event. See Flux docs [example](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/dispatcher.html)